# How to make the rows of a dataframe scale by one or more positions?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame with 2 columns, but I have errors only in the first column and I need to read them by scrolling only the rows of the first column.

```
 player <-  c( "ronaldo", "neymar", "zidane", "error", "morata", "suarez")
code <- c("ron897", "ney548", "zid176", "mor458", "sua932", "rob346" )


df <- cbind(player, code)

      player     code    
[1,] "ronaldo" "ron897"
[2,] "neymar"  "ney548"
[3,] "zidane"  "zid176"
[4,] "error"   "mor458"
[5,] "morata"  "sua932"
[6,] "suarez"  "rob346"
```

I would like to achieve this. Maybe I need a function that once found "error" deletes it and makes
the rows of the columns scale one line up

```
      player           code    
[1,] "ronaldo"        "ron897"
[2,] "neymar"         "ney548"
[3,] "zidane"         "zid176"
[4,] "morata"         "mor458"
[5,] "suarez"         "sua932"
[6,] "rob carlos"     "rob346"
```

Comment: Where did "rob carlos" come from?

Comment: This is an example of the problem I have. In particular, I have a dataframe of 1000 and more lines in which that "error" appears more than once and does not make me match the title to the right code

Comment: @AnilGoyal "Rob Carlos" It would still have been a character value

Answer (score 2):

In effect, what you're trying to do is to delete entries in only one column. This is very possible, but you need to consider how to ensure that both columns stay the same length. The easiest way is to pad the `player` column after deleting values. If you pad it with `"error"` values you can think of this as a sorting operation:

```
df$player2 <- c(player[player != "error"], player[player == "error"])
df
#>    player   code player2
#> 1 ronaldo ron897 ronaldo
#> 2  neymar ney548  neymar
#> 3  zidane zid176  zidane
#> 4   error mor458  morata
#> 5  morata sua932  suarez
#> 6  suarez rob346   error
```